# How do I pass a PK or slug to a DetailView using RequestFactory in Django?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-views

I'm trying to use [RequestFactory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/advanced/#module-django.test.client) to test a DetailView with the following test case:

```
def test_device_homepage(self):
    request = self.factory.get('/devices/1/', {'pk': 1})

    response = DeviceView.as_view()(request)

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 404)
```

When I run the above test, however, I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: Generic detail view DeviceView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.
```

If I print the request after creation, I can see the following:

```
<WSGIRequest
path:/devices/1/,
GET:<QueryDict: {u'pk': [u'1']}>,
```

As far as I can tell, that should be all that the DetailView requires to be able to progress past the point in code that's generating the above error message.

For completeness the full traceback is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/vagrant/devices/tests/test_views.py", line 17, in test_device_homepage
response = DeviceView.as_view()(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 86, in dispatch
return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py", line 108, in get
self.object = self.get_object()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py", line 48, in get_object
% self.__class__.__name__)
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Thanks to the #django channel on Freenode IRC, I found the following method is the correct one to pass parameters all the way through to the view:

```
response = DeviceView.as_view()(request, pk=1)
```

I hope this helps somebody else attempting to use RequestFactory to test DetailView or DeleteView etc